# CSS selector for an element having class .a and class .b

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style an element that has both class `.a` and class `.b`. How do I do it?

The order the classes appear in the HTML might vary.

```
<style>
    div.a ? div.b {
        color:#f00;
    }
</style>
<div class="a">text not red</div>
<div class="b">text not red</div>
<div class="a b">red text</div>
<div class="b a">red text</div>
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's entirely possible.  If you specify two classes on an element (without any spaces), that means that it must have both for the rule to apply.

```css
div.a {
  color: blue;
}
div.b {
  color: green;
}
div.a.b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  A
</div>
<div class="b">
  B
</div>
<div class="a b">
  AB
</div>
```

Comment: Is this supported in IE9? I am having issues where elements with just one of the classes are picking up the style. This is the doc-type I am using..

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: @Dib, I created an example using that doctype on JS Bin (https://jsbin.com/xepemipuqo/1/edit) which works just fine in IE 9.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 14):

Class selectors can be combined:

```
div.a.b {
  color: red;
}
```

Quoting from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html):

> To match a subset of "class" values, each value must be preceded by a ".".
>
> For example, the following rule matches any P element whose "class" attribute has been assigned a list of space-separated values that includes "pastoral" and "marine":
>
> ```
> p.marine.pastoral { color: green }
> ```
>
> This rule matches when `class="pastoral blue aqua marine"` but does not match for `class="pastoral blue"`.

Answer (score 6):

```css
div[class~="a"][class~="b"] {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I love this but worth mentioning that legacy browser support is fairly low.

Answer (score -2):

```html
/* select div tag having class a and b together */
<style>
div.a.b
{ 
    color:#f00;
}
</style>
<div class="a">text not red</div>
<div class="b">text not red</div>
<div class="a b">red text</div>
<div class="b a">red text</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

Yeah, use a common class, or why not, JavaScript if the content changes dynamically